# I'm getting data from the Spotify API, but after a while running it marks an error and starts logging the same information over and over

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm trying to understand Spotify API. This small code console logs the information of the current beat of the song that the user is listening to.

It works fine but after a few seconds running, it logs an error and after that error it starts logging the information of the same beat over and over again. Any ideas? Here is my code and thank you in advance!

```
var spotifyApi, spotifyToken;
var current, currentId, timeProgress, beatStart, beatsTotal;
var dataArray = [];
var beatsArray = [];
var spotifyToken = 'token';
spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();
spotifyApi.setAccessToken( spotifyToken );

init();

function init(){
  onReceiveCurrent();
}

function onReceiveCurrent ( err, data ) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  spotifyApi.getMyCurrentPlaybackState({}, onReceiveCurrent );
  currentId = data.item.id;
  timeProgress = data.progress_ms;
  spotifyApi.getAudioAnalysisForTrack(currentId, onReceiveAnalysisCallback);
}

function onReceiveAnalysisCallback ( err, data ) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  for (var i=0; i<data.beats.length; i++) {
    beatsArray[i] = data.beats[i].start;
  }

  var found = beatsArray.find(function (element) {
        return element >= timeProgress/1000;
  });

  var a = beatsArray.indexOf(found);
  beatStart = data.beats[a];
  console.log(beatStart);
}
```

Here's the error:

[image]

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: How many times are `init()` called? You may be running the same api more than once.

Comment: I just edited into the posts a picture of the error it logs, thank you Sean!

Comment: I think I'm just calling it once at the beginning of the code, thank you John!

Comment: Along John's line of thinking, a 429 error is caused due to too many requests. How are you running this script? If it is inside of any loop or re-render then that could cause a 429.

Comment: The Spotify method "getMyCurrentPlaybackState" asks for a callback function, i put the same function the method was in so it keep calling it over and over. Maybe that's the problem, I'm quite new at this. How else can i keep it running? Thank you Daly!

Comment: Oh I see it, give me one sec to type out the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've accidentally created an infinite loop in the `onReceiveCurrent` method, which calls `getMyCurrentPlaybackState` which has a callback of `onReceiveCurrent`. It's calling itself over and over until it hits Spotify's limit and returns a 429.

The callback should be a separate function like so:

```
function callSpotify () {
  spotifyApi.getMyCurrentPlaybackState({}, onReceiveStateCallback );
}

function onReceiveStateCallback(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  currentId = data.item.id;
  timeProgress = data.progress_ms;
  spotifyApi.getAudioAnalysisForTrack(currentId, onReceiveAnalysisCallback);
}
```

Comment: The `setInterval(function, milliseconds)` function can be used to repeatedly call `getMyCurrentPlaybackState` at an interval which Spotify allows, you will have to do some research to find what value of milliseconds satisfies this constraint.